# VS Code Python Formatting: Change max line-length with autopep8 / yapf / black

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting

I am experimenting with different python formatters and would like to increase the max line length. Ideally without editing the `settings.json` file. Is there a way to achieve that?
[image: select formatter]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For all three formatters, the max line length can be increased with additional arguments passed in from settings, i.e.:

- autopep8 args: `--max-line-length=120`
- black args: `--line-length=120`
- yapf args: `--style={based_on_style: google, column_limit: 120, indent_width: 4}`

Hope that helps someone in the future!

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to work around with Jupyter Notebook in VSCode for kind of matter?

Comment: What is the JSON key?

Comment: the setting seems gone?

Answer (score 2):

@tkazik answered his own question correctly, however, I thought it would be helpful to include some references:

**VSCode documentation** on using Python formatters:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting

**autopep8** command line options:
https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/#usage

- Note that there is also an option to point the formatter to a global config file
- Additionally, if you have a local or global config file in the expected location, these preferences will be used automatically by the formatter in VSCode (https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/#configuration)

**black** command line options:
https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/the_basics.html#command-line-options

**yapf** command line options:
https://github.com/google/yapf#usage

Comment: And how would you feed them to VS Code? He asked for a settings.json key.