# My VSCode word wrapper width is too small. Word wrapping too soon

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, word-wrap, prettier

For some reason my word wrapping has gotten messed up in VSCode. The word wrap occurs after saving. I do like this feature but I need it to stop wrapping so soon. There is plenty of space left on the right side still. I have prettier installed and it is set to the default 80 line width. I have changed this and restarted VSCode and the problem remains the same. I have even disabled prettier and it is still doing this. I have also gone into the word wrapper for VSCode and ensured it was off. Can anyone tell me what is causing this and how to resolve it?

This...
[image]

should look more like this..
[image]

And in VSCode I have changed these things with no luck...
[image]
[image]

Also, I think this problem only exists in this current project. Maybe I installed a python extension causing this??
Maybe these...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image below is located in the settings. This resolves my issue.
[image]

Also found here...
[VS Code Python Formatting: Change max line-length with autopep8 / yapf / black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71078751/vs-code-python-formatting-change-max-line-length-with-autopep8-yapf-black)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is a function of **formatting**. You can turn it off in settings.

Tips:

`Pylance` is the integration of `Python` and `Jupyter Notebook` extensions, both of which are official extensions of Microsoft. There is no problem keeping them. :)

Comment: I believe this gives me the option to turn off the formatting but this is NOT what I want. I like the formatting, I just think the wrap width is off. It should word wrap longer lines on save. Do you know how to change this?

Comment: What formatting tool do you use? yapf，autopep8 or black?

Comment: I think autopep8.

Comment: Your question led me to the solution. Thanks you! I will post an image of it below.